# Why will the Knights not have any of their players picked by the Kraken?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, expansion

I find it weird that for some reason, the Knights are not included in the list of teams that will have to sacrifice a player to the Kraken.

What is the reasoning with this? Is it that they are too new a team and they are given a chance by not letting one of their players get taken, or it's that the 30 picks system lands on a nice number and they decided to not change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the Golden Knights are a recent expansion team themselves, and so they don't have to give up a player to Kraken, the newest expansion team.

This is based on the agreement the Knights made when joining the league. They wouldn't be part of the expansion draft for a number of years, but also wouldn't get a share of the expansion fee either. See [this](https://www.espn.com/nhl/story/_/id/31811624/how-nhl-expansion-draft-work-seattle-kraken-schedule-format-rules-players-available) ESPN article:

> The Golden Knights do not have to give up a player in the expansion
> draft, a deal owner Bill Foley struck with the NHL in their original
> franchise agreement in 2016. The only downside for Vegas? Foley
> doesn't get a cut of Seattle's $650 million expansion fee, which
> equates to a $21.67 million check for the other 30 teams.

Also as a side note, most NHL expansion teams over time tend to take years, sometimes even a whole decade, before becoming contenders. The Knights are an exception to the trend. Had they followed the usual trajectory, they would've been a mediocre team, with little expectation to be part of the expansion draft.

Comment: More specifically, it was in the original Knights franchise agreement that they would not be subject to any further expansion drafts for (some number of years I can't find right now). See e.g. "Why is Vegas exempt from the expansion draft?" at [ESPN](https://www.espn.co.uk/nhl/story/_/id/31811624/how-nhl-expansion-draft-work-seattle-kraken-schedule-format-rules-players-available).

Comment: OK yeah so its an agreement, and an usual one at that. And that also comes with that they dont get a cut of the Kraken expansion fee.

Comment: Correct. I couldn't find the exact wording, but see my second paragraph, added more info including the expansion fee

Comment: "Had they followed the usual trajectory, they would've been a mediocre team..."  ...like the Kraken ended up being in their first season.